How to reproduce "doorkeeper_authorize!" in a separated ResourceServer
For our implementation, we've separated the ResourceServer from the AuthorizationServer into different applications. So our RS has to make an API call to the AS to confirm that an AccessToken is active and has the correct scopes. We thought that the token/introspect would handle that functionality, but some components like "rotate on use" don't carry over (the only token that gets rotated is the one used by the ResourceServer to make the check, not the token used by the ClientApplication.
We were thinking that we need an API endpoint that calls into the doorkeeper_authorize! helper so that all of the behaviors we want are carried through.
Is this a thing? A plugin? Separating the RS from the AS seems like a common enough design choice.
